# C++ wrapper (shell) for C# program

Tags: c#, c++

There was information from the person that it is possible to "wrap" the C # application in the C ++ application while hiding the source code. It's true? If so, how can this be done?
Are there any programs or code for the future C ++ application.

P.S. When I started learning C #, I did not think that there would be problems associated with encrypting the source code.

Comment: Ngen? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator

Comment: Very hard to guess why you'd consider encrypting source code, keep it on your dev machine.  Use the correct Google search terms, query for "c# obfuscator".  85K hits is enough for everybody.  And do worry a bit less about anybody wanting to steal it, at best they'd want to help you improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly Obfuscate Programms, wich makes it harder to decompile them into humanly readable sourcecode. But you can not prevent decompilation - as long as the Programm can be interpreted by the OS, .NET Framework and CPU it can be reverse engineered. And even that much might throw a monkeywrench into just about any Optimisation the Framework tries to apply to your code.

Your question also has a classical mistake in understanding C# and .NET. The language of the source code does not mater. Everything you compile in any .NET Language - C# included is turned into (MS)IL code. IL has actually a surprising amount of design similarties to JavaByte code.

So your qiestion should be to wrap ".NET", "IL" or "MSIL" code into native code. And I am not ever certain if that adds any additional layer of obfuscation. Internally .NET Executeables are .NET DLL's with a Manifest and some [Native Bootstrapping code anyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). For the framework to execute the IL, it has to exist in memory in a non-encrypted format at runtime.